# У меня есть txt файл, в нем куча ссылок, и мне из них нужно каждую обрезать

Tags: c#

Как мне написать алгоритм для их обрезания и узнать, сколько там их. Например, объясню подробнее. У нас есть тхт с куча ссылок, мне нужен алгоритм, который будет брать ссылку, обрезать её на 1 символ и вставлять в другой текстовый документ, помогите с этим алгоритмом, кол-во ссылок в тхт неизвестно. Желательно на C#. Ссылки разделены пробелом.

Comment: `Как мне написать алгоритм` - открываете Visual Studio/Rider/Eclipse/Intellij Idea и пишите, в чем проблема? Приложите код, который вы пытались написать

Comment: а пример содержимого файла можно?

Comment: Я не птылачя писать, я не знал сам алгоритм, пример в файле "https://inst/obama https://inst/trump" вот так будет в тхт файле

Comment: var result = File.ReadAllText().Split(' ').ToArray();

Comment: Ок, как дальше брать каждую ссылку и обрезать её?

Answer (score 1):

Алгоритм будет такой:

1. Считать содержимое файла.
2. Распарсить считанное содержимое на отдельные элементы (в Вашем случае, на строки, каждая из которых является ссылкой).
3. Пройти циклом по каждому элементу:

   3.1. выполняя преобразование (в Вашем случае, удаляя последний символ)

   3.2. записывая преобразованный элемент в другой файл

Что Вы сделали и что не получилось?

**UPD:**

2. Как Вам написал @pasha goroshko в комментарии, парсинг проще всего сделать через [string.Split](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/api/system.string.split?view=netframework-4.8):

   string[] source = File.ReadAllText("Путь_к_исходному_файлу").Split('Ваш_разделитель');
3. Далее реализуем цикл и пишем в результирующий файл, используя, например, [File.AppendText](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/api/system.io.file.appendtext?view=netframework-4.8)

   ```
   using (StreamWriter writer = File.AppendText("путь_к_результирующему_файлу")) 
   {
       for (int i = 0; i < source.Length; i++)
       {
           string sourceI = source[i]; //получаем элемент распарсенного массива (исходная строка)
           string resultI = sourceI.Substring(0, sourceI.Length - 1); //обрезаем строку
           writer.AppendText(resultI); //здесь пишем в результирующий файл
           //при необходимости таким же образом добавляем нужный Вам разделитель
       }
   }
   ```

Comment: 2,3,3.1 не умею делать, подскажите кодом, 1 смотря как считывать файл(побайтово)? Если не сложно скиньте со всеми действиями

Comment: @PrinceTag Я конечно извиняюсь, но вы только сегодня начали изучать C#?

Comment: Нет, я его давно знаю, скажите как делать 2-3, я с файлами до этого момента не работал, в основном с парсерами сайтов

Comment: @PrinceTag Ну, если давно знаете, но должны знать циклы, например `foreach`, работу со строками, а если чуточку погуглить, то чтение файла по строкам легко находится `File.ReadAllLines`.

Comment: @Prince Tag обновил ответ с примером

Comment: @МаксЖуков AppendText не работает нормально, он выдает сразу 2 ссылки, я с ним промучался весь день ища баг, есть какие-нибудь альтенативные способы, может сабстрингом как-то?